# Can search results on a specific library be setup to show for Authenticated users, but not Anonymous users?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, search, search-results

I have a document library I'd like to:

1. Be accessible for both anonymous and authenticated Users

   But only be searchable by authenticated users, show up in their results only

So far I haven't really seen a way to accomplish this in SharePoint 2013.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOB way to achieve it.

As a workaround, I suggest you use different search results pages for Authenticated users and Anonymous users. For Anonymous users' search result page, add a query into the search result web part to exclude the library path. You can have a try.